# Need to add text field in custom payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

ACL is my custom payment method now i want to add custom field below ACL Option in Checkout Page.

PFA

[image]

Comment: Is the attribute "bank_name" created? If yes, which type of attributes you created?

Comment: No, I have not created an attribute

Comment: Which attribute type you want to have for "bank_name"? Customer or customer address?

Comment: a user just fills the bank info, account number for that payment method and admin can see that information. That's it.
Can you explain the flow how to create this functionality?

Comment: Every order is different for "bank_name" from the same customer?

Comment: yes, the same customer can insert the bank_name for every order.

Comment: OK, I get it. That means you need a order attribute. I'll answer you soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83426/discussion-between-akash-patel-and-py-yick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, there are 3 parts:

1. Create Order Attribute
2. Insert attribute when placing order
3. Read the Order Attribute in payment module

**Create Order Attribute**

For creating order attribute, you MUST use setup script with the following code:

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    protected $quoteSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var SalesSetupFactory
     */
    protected $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup $quoteInstaller */
            $quoteInstaller = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'quote_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);

            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup $salesInstaller */
            $salesInstaller = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'sales_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);

            //Add attributes to quote
            $entityAttributesCodes = [
                'bank_name' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            ];

            foreach ($entityAttributesCodes as $code => $type) {
                $quoteInstaller->addAttribute('quote', $code, ['type' => $type, 'length' => 255, 'visible' => true, 'nullable' => true,]);
                $salesInstaller->addAttribute('order', $code, ['type' => $type, 'length' => 255, 'visible' => true, 'nullable' => true,]);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I used upgrade script as example, but you can use inscript to perform the same function too.

**Insert attribute when placing order**

This process is a little bit tricky but I think it's still OK for you.

- Create new file `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml` with the following code:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
      <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
          <attribute code="bank_name" type="string"/>
      </extension_attributes>
  </config>
  ```
- Create file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` with the following code:

  ```
  var config = {
      config: {
          mixins: {
              'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                  'Vendor_Module/js/order/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
              }
          }
      }
  };
  ```
- Create new file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/order/set-shipping-information-mixin.js` with the following code:

  ```
  define([
      'jquery',
      'mage/utils/wrapper',
      'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
  ], function ($, wrapper, quote) {
      'use strict';

      return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

          return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
              var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
              if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                  shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
              }

              // you can extract value of extension attribute from any place (in this example I use customAttributes approach)
              shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['bank_name'] = jQuery('input[name="bank_name"]').val();
              // pass execution to original action ('Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information')
              return originalAction();
          });
      };
  });
  ```
- Create file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
          <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
              <arguments>
                  <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                          <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                              <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                  <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                      <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                          <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                              <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                  <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                      <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                          <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                              <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                  <!-- Your form declaration here -->
                                                                  <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                                      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/order_attr</item>
                                                                      <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                          <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/order_attr</item>
                                                                      </item>
                                                                      <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                          <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                              <!-- uiComponent is used as a wrapper for form fields (its template will render all children as a list) -->
                                                                              <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                              <!-- the following display area is used in template (see below) -->
                                                                              <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
                                                                              <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                  <item name="bank_name" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                          <!-- customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately) -->
                                                                                          <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                          <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                          <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                      </item>
                                                                                      <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                      <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.bank_name</item>
                                                                                      <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Clearance Full Name</item>
                                                                                      <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                                      <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                          <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                                      </item>
                                                                                  </item>
                                                                              </item>
                                                                          </item>
                                                                      </item>
                                                                  </item>
                                                              </item>
                                                          </item>
                                                      </item>
                                                  </item>
                                              </item>
                                          </item>
                                      </item>
                                  </item>
                              </item>
                          </item>
                      </item>
                  </argument>
              </arguments>
          </referenceBlock>
      </body>
  </page>
  ```
- Create file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/order_attr.html` with the following code:

  ```
  <div>
      <form id="custom-checkout-form" class="form" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
          <fieldset class="fieldset">
              <legend data-bind="i18n: 'Clearance Info'"></legend>
              <div><!-- ko i18n: 'This is clearance description' --><!-- /ko --></div>
              <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form-fields') -->
              <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
              <!--/ko-->
          </fieldset>
      </form>
  </div>
  ```
- Create file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/order_attr.js` with the following code:

  ```
  define([
      'Magento_Ui/js/form/form'
  ], function(Component) {
      'use strict';
      return Component.extend({
          initialize: function () {
              this._super();
              // component initialization logic
              return this;
          },

          /**
           * Form submit handler
           *
           * This method can have any name.
           */
          onSubmit: function() {
              // trigger form validation
              this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
              this.source.trigger('customCheckoutForm.data.validate');

              // verify that form data is valid
              if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                  // data is retrieved from data provider by value of the customScope property
                  var formData = this.source.get('customCheckoutForm');
                  // do something with form data
                  console.dir(formData);
              }
          }
      });
  });
  ```
- Create file `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml` with the following code:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
          <plugin name="save-in-quote" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AddOrderAttrToQuote" sortOrder="10"/>
      </type>
  </config>
  ```
- Create new file `app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/AddOrderAttrToQuote.php` with the following code:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;


  class AddOrderAttrToQuote
  {
      protected $quoteRepository;

      public function __construct(
          \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
      ) {
          $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
      }

      /**
       * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
       * @param $cartId
       * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
       */
      public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
          \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
          $cartId,
          \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
      ) {
          $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress()->getExtensionAttributes();
          $bank_name = $extAttributes->getBankName();
          $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
          $quote->setBankName($bank_name);
          $extAttributes->setBankName("");
      }
  }
  ```
- Create new file `app/code/Cleargo/NewAttributes/etc/events.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
          <observer name="handle_order_attrs" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\HandleOrderAttrs" />
      </event>
  </config>
  ```
- Create new file `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/HandleOrderAttrs.php` with the following code:

  ```
  <?php        
  namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

  use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
  use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

  class HandleOrderAttrs implements ObserverInterface
  {
      public function execute(Observer $observer)
      {
          $order = $observer->getOrder();
          $quote = $observer->getQuote();
          //Load the values
          $bank_name = $quote->getData("bank_name");
          $order->setData('bank_name', $bank_name)
              ->save();
      }
  }
  ```

**Read the Order Attribute in payment module**

For case 3, seems it's from 3rd party module. Anyway, if you want to get the value of `bank_name` from order, you can use the following code:

```
$order->getData('bank_name')
```

**Conslusion**

It's quite a lot of work to do for an order attribute, but once you get the key point, everything will go smooth.

Comment: Thanks, You have added a custom tab in shipping information but I want to add below my custom payment method. When I click on payment method then it's shows

Comment: @Akash  did you find any solution. for the same